# OS X: Capture keyboard input without visually taking focus

Tags: macos, cocoa, keyboard, focus

I'd like to develop an app that lives in the background but can show some UI that captures keyboard input when asked, like Spotlight.

[image]

When Spotlight is active, it gets keyboard input but the window in the background still has visual focus. (Any insertion point in the background application goes away though.)

How can I create this effect myself?

Comment: Quicksilver does this successfully, so it's not an internal API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The window must…

- be a subclass of `NSPanel` which
- overrides `canBecomeKeyWindow` to return `true` and
- has been initialized with a style mask including `NSNonactivatingPanelMask`.

Then you can bring it to the front with `window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)`, even if your application is not active.

Comment: Thank you for the response, this worked for me. I know this was many years ago but could I ask where did you get this from? I cannot find any documentation on this.